# Is PKCS#1 V2.0 implemented for Java?

Tags: java, encryption, rsa, pkcs#1

I need encrypt data using exactly the PKCS#1 V2.0 encryption method (defined in item 7.2.1 of [the PKCS#1V2 specification](ftp://ftp.rsasecurity.com/pub/pkcs/ascii/pkcs-1v2.asc)).

Is it already implemented for Java?

I'm thinking in something like just pass a parameter to javax.crypto.Cipher specifying "PKCS#1V2", I wonder if there is something like this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

PKCS#1 v2.0 encryption is usually called OAEP encryption. So:

```
Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/OAEPWithSHA1AndMGF1Padding");
```

The place to look is the Java Cryptography Architecture documents: [Standard Algorithm Name Documentation](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/StandardNames.html) or [Sun Providers Documentation](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/SunProviders.html#SunJCEProvider).

As you can see the SunJCE provider supports the following variations of OAEP:

- OAEPWITHMD5ANDMGF1PADDING
- OAEPWITHSHA1ANDMGF1PADDING
- (OAEPWITHSHA-1ANDMGF1PADDING)
- OAEPWITHSHA-256ANDMGF1PADDING
- OAEPWITHSHA-384ANDMGF1PADDING
- OAEPWITHSHA-512ANDMGF1PADDING

Comment: Sun Providers Documentation, yes, Standard Algorithm Name Docs, no. Sun does not promise to implement everything they have reserved a name for. As an example, the "ECIES" algorithm name is reserved, but no Sun provider implements it.

Comment: The Standard Algorithm Name Documentation helps you find the correct name instead of "PKCS#1V2". The Sun Providers Documentation helps you find out whether the Sun provider implements it or if you should try to find another provider.

Comment: @RasmusFaber Looks like OAEP (Optimal Asymmetric Encryption Padding) it's just the padding definition. Is PKCS1V2 just about padding?

Comment: @Tom Brito: Why don't read the spec for yourself? http://www.rfc-editor.org/cgi-bin/rfcdoctype.pl?loc=RFC&letsgo=3447&type=http&file_format=txt

Comment: I didn't found this names, but found XMLCipher.RSA_OAEP in apache commons, that is the same thing. Anyway, thanks!